# How can I complete a full circle polar distort with ImageMagick CLI?

Tags: imagemagick

I am using ImageMagick (Windows v7.1.1-15) CLI and want to create a polar image from a rectangular map image.

Here is the command I'm using, but you'll see that it is missing a small arc. Any recommendations to create a complete polar distort?

```
magick convert cart.jpg -virtual-pixel HorizontalTile -background Black -distort Polar 0  polar.jpg
```

[Rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr8NY.jpg)
[Polar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmErU.jpg)

I tried to adjust the start and end angle, but did not get the complete polar distort as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a white border and a black outline. If you remove them, you get closer in Imagemagick. Adjust as desired

Input:

[image]

```
magick map.jpg -fuzz 25% -trim +repage -shave 2x2 +repage -virtual-pixel HorizontalTile  -background Black   -distort Polar 0   polar_map.jpg
```

[image]

In IM 7, use magick, not magick convert.

Comment: Worked like a charm - thank you for the prompt reply, working solution, and introduction to the work I'll need to do to learn more on V7. Thanks!